# Call Retrofit without having Value

Tags: java, android, kotlin

how to call Retrofit  GET method api in which no value will pass in GET(")

this is my code

```
@GET(" ")
fun fetchData(): Call<List<Data>>
```

this is my BASE URL https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/All

and it cant have backslash at end

Comment: shouldn't your base url be something like `https://abhi-debug.github.io/` and the @GET fun be `"Caption/All"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @GET(".")
  fun fetchData(): Call<List<Data>>
```

Pass `"."` as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have a base URL like: https://abhi-debug.github.io/

And then add this:

```
@GET("Caption/All")
fun fetchData(): Call<List<Data>>
```

Comment: [ {
      "id": 1,
  "title": "ALL",
  "url": "https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/All/"
 },

this is my json file so i am fecthing base url from this json i cant separate base url

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can use @GET(".") to indicate that your url is the same as the base url.

```
@GET(".") 
Call<List<Data>> fetchData();
```

**Solution 2**

You can pass URL to reuest as you mention you got URL in json response

```
@GET()
Call<List<Data>> fetchData(@Url String url);
```

and call

```
Call<List<Data>> call = retrofitInterface.fetchData("https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/All");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Data>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Data>> call, Response<List<Data>> response) {
        Log.i(TAG, response.body().toString());

        List<Data> body = response.body();

        Log.i(TAG, body.get(0).getId()+"");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Data>> call, Throwable t) {
        // Log error here since request failed
        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/demo.json

how to by pass this if url do not have  / at the end in base url

Comment: In Solution 1- @GET("./") as following approach https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1567#issuecomment-180115150

In solution 2 -You can concate string like this retrofitInterface.fetchData("https://abhi-debug.github.io/Caption/All"+"/");

Answer (score 0):

In your Api Interface use this method

```
@GET
Call<JsonObject> fetchData(@Url String config);
```